# Cómo multiplicar números con decimales en Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Compañeros estoy tratando de multiplicar esta operación en bash pero me dá error, me indica esto:
Indique el capital a invertir: 18000
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

les agradeceria su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas Noel, la próxima pregunta porfavor pega código en lugar de imagen, es mejor para todos! Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituye `0,02` por `0.02`

#### solución

```
#/bin/bash

read -p "Indique el capital a invertir:" cap_inv
reaporcentaje=0.02
ganancia=$(echo "scale=2;$cap_inv*$reaporcentaje" | bc)
echo $ganancia
```

#### comprobación

```
➜  ~ ./sum.sh 
Indique el capital a invertir:
2000
40.00
```

#### explicación

Un SO se puede extender por todo el mundo, pero cada país trata de forma distinta la moneda, los números, el idioma... A eso se le llaman los [`LOCALES`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) precisamente, porqué son variables locales.

Seguramente tengas unos locales que hagan referencia a la lengua española, de España o país semejante, lo puedes ver con el comando:

```
➜  ~ locale
LANG=ca_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
➜  ~
```

En este caso, hacemos referencia a `LC_NUMERIC`. Este `locale` define si en X país el separador decimal es un `.` o una `,`.

Hasta aqui todo perfecto. El problema esta en que [`bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC23) no habla con los `locale`, todo debe pasar por separador decimal por punto.

Comment: Por favor, no respondas a dos preguntas sobre exactamente el mismo tema, sobre todo si el autor de ambas preguntas es el mismo. Responde la que encuentres mejor planteada y deja algún comentario al AP para que elimine una de las dos preguntas, de esa manera se mantiene un mejor orden en el sitio.